# Android Toggle switch's text on the right

Tags: android, switch-statement, togglebutton

I had googled around but there seem no way to may the text appears on the right instead of on the default Left. image explained.

May i know is there way to make the text ("sound") appear on the right for Android Switch (Android classify them the same) ?

[Switch Button](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html)

[image: Switch Android Text Right]

Comment: But that will be two pieces of UI and post unnecessary alignment issue.

Comment: there is no alignment issue ... and you are not used toggle button . It is switch button .edit your question ... try this link may be it help you http://ankri.de/switch-button-for-android-2-3-gingerbread/

Answer (score 0):

[image]I don't know Why you are struggling with it but when I tried below code text appears right side of toggle button

```
<Switch
        android:text="Switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        />
```

Comment: jiteshmohite, not helpful, 
@Joakim, thanks.
text still appear on the LEFT.

`<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/skip"
    android:text="@string/str_med_tg_sw_skip"
    android:textOn="@string/str_med_tg_sw_skip_on"
    android:checked="true">
</Switch>`

Comment: in which device or emulator you are trying this and what is the api

Comment: can you please check it to emulator or any other devices. i am not able to get these isssue on my emulator

Comment: please check it

Comment: on HTC butterfly Android API 18 (4.3) [Phone info](http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_butterfly-5118.php)

can you edit and provide a screen capture image ?
tested on another device Android 4.4.2 (API 19), same result.
no, your text (Switch) shown on LEFT, I wanted "switch" on the RIGHT.